# JSON in rel, finding DOM element with jQuery doesn't seem to make sense

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So although my program is working as desired, I can't wrap my head around why it is working and it seems like it shouldn't be.  I would love some clarification.

I have a div element that has some JSON in the rel attribute.  specifically:

```
<div class="download_button" rel='{"songId": "10", "listening_to_what": "search"}'></div>
```

I have many many many divs like the one above on the same page.

Later I am trying to find the next element using javascript/jquery like this:

```
var next = $("[rel=10]").next().attr("rel");
```

this code gives me the desired result---it finds the div where the JSON's songId is 10 in the rel attribute...I don't understand why it works though!  I originally was only storing the number ID in the rel, and this is why my JS was only looking for rel=10.  I updated the rel attribute to be a JSON and it still works.

Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: It does not seem to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MQfgx/ and it should not work.  I think there's something else going on in your code than what you've shown here.

Comment: likely using a plugin that reads the metadata

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` selects the immediately following sibling element which implies there are at-least two elements: http://api.jquery.com/next

So you probably have an element just before this element who's `rel="10"`. Any chance that's the case? If not what does your HTML structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `div` element is not defined to include the 'rel' attribute under any modern HTML specification:

**HTML 4.01:**

- Div specification -- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4
- Global attributes -- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#coreattrs

**HTML 5 (HTML)**:

- Div specification -- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element
- Global attributes -- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#global-attributes

Therefore, including a 'rel' attribute on a `div` element implies undefined behavior. It also doesn't make sense to use the 'rel' attribute in this manner. This attribute is meant to indicate the relationship of a link to the surrounding content. Indeed, there is a specific [list of allowed values](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes) for the 'rel' attribute.

The attribute you should be using is the [data-*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attribute. You could include a `data-json` attribute, or something more descriptive than that (e.g. `data-song-info`).

Further, you gain [enhanced support from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) for the `data-*` attributes. Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="srchrslt" data-song-id="10" data-song-name="Stranglehold">
  ...
</div>
```

You can then do the following:

```
$('.srchrslt').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log('Song id = ' + $this.data('songId'));
});
```

Additionally, as mentioned in the comments, you could also do:

```
<div class='srchrslt' data-song-data='{"songId": 10, "listening_to_what": "search"}'>
  ...
</div>

$('.srchrslt').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      rsltData = $.parseJSON($this.data('songData'));

  console.log('Song id = ' + rsltData.songId);
});
```

Notice that I used single quotes on both attributes. Technically, this is a matter of style, as the [specification allows](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-0) mixing them. However, as I mentioned in the comments, I don't think it is a good idea to go this route. Notice this warning in the specification:

> followed by the attribute value, which, in addition to the requirements given above for attribute values, must not contain any literal U+0027 APOSTROPHE characters (')

If your JSON ends up containing an escaped single quote, e.g. `'{"foo": "bar\'s"}'`, then your HTML attribute value will be invalid. Thus, you'll end up with undefined behavior again. Your JSON encoder would need to return `{"foo": "bar&apos;s"}` instead. You'll run into the same problem with double quotes:

> followed by the attribute value, which, in addition to the requirements given above for attribute values, must not contain any literal U+0022 QUOTATION MARK characters (")

Comment: Else you can use `data-songdata="{}"`. And in your javascript `JSON.parse($('div.yourclassname').data());`

Comment: @juzerali true, but I think it's cleaner to use an attribute for each property (if there are few properties).